# Converting A+"COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT" to Á

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Mac stores filenames with á as "LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT" instead of as "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE". If I am reading file names containing áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ how can I convert them to the combined versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'a\u0301')
'á'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'a\u0301').encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\xe1'
```